# Formation of a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

```
Employee  (EmployeeNo(PK),shopID(FK1) employeeName, employeeAddress) 

Shop      (shopID(PK), shopName, shopAddress) 

Comment   (EmployeeNo(FK), employeeComments)
```

Is it possible to run a query showing the names of all the employees who have left a comment in the comments table even if the employee name is not in the table?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select employeeName from employee,comment
where employee.employeeNo = comment.employeeNo
```

I think it is a simple join which you have to use.

Comment: Better to use `SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeName FROM Employee AS E JOIN Comment AS C ON E.EmployeeNo = C.EmployeeNo`, avoiding duplicates and using the explicit JOIN notation.  The old-style implicit join with commas in the FROM list has been obsolescent since JOIN was standardized in SQL-92.

Answer (score 1):

**It is actually a small query that you can easily learn.**

Following query will return Employee Name who left the comment and the Comment left by him

```
SELECT employeeName, employeeComments
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Comment ON (Employee.EmployeeNo = Comment.EmployeeNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.employeeName
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Comment C ON E.EmployeeNo = C.EmployeeNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the employees who have commented we have following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employeeName
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.EmployeeNo IN (SELECT EmployeeNo
                              FROM Comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.employeeName
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Comment C ON E.EmployeeNo = C.EmployeeNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeName
FROM [Employee] AS e 
RIGHT JOIN [Comment] AS c 
ON e.EmployeeNo = c.EmployeeNo
```

OR

```
SELECT e.employeeName
FROM [Employee] AS e 
WHERE e.EmployeeNo IN (
                        SELECT EmployeeNo
                        FROM [Comment]
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select e.employeeName,
           c.employeeComment 
    from Employee e
    right join Comment c on
    e.EmployeeNo=c.EmployeeNo
```

this will give you employee name & comment